# What is the form of link function in this BUGS multinomial regression example?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, bugs

The alligators [example](http://www.openbugs.net/Examples/Aligators.html) from openbugs examples repository is the same example that comes with winbugs. 
Basically this is a multinomial logistic regression example in which the outcome variable has 5 possible values and there are two categorical independent variables. The outcome is the food preference of an alligator and independent variables are the size of the crocodile and the lake in which the crocodile lives.

The examples page above describes the model as follows:

[image]

And the code that is supposed to represent this model is:

```
# LIKELIHOOD   
       for (i in 1 : I) { # loop around lakes
          for (j in 1 : J) { # loop around sizes

            # Multinomial response
            X[i,j,1 : K] ~ dmulti( p[i, j, 1 : K] , n[i, j] )

            n[i, j] <- sum(X[i, j, ])

            for (k in 1 : K) { # loop around foods
                p[i, j, k] <- phi[i, j, k] / sum(phi[i, j, ])
                log(phi[i ,j, k]) <- alpha[k] + beta[i, k] + gamma[j, k]
            }

          }
       }
```

This code (commented out and cleaned up) is the same in both openbugs example page and in the example that comes with Winbugs.

I can't see the linear function that links lake and alligator size to choice of food for the alligator. Both the textual definition of the model and the code has only coefficients for alpha, beta and gamma, but their sum is simply exponentiated.

I would expect

```
alpha + beta * LAKE + gamma * SIZE
```

as the linear function but as it is, I can only see coefficients but not the variables.

So how is this model connecting covariates to probabilities here?

Comment: The link is the log function. The BUGS code is fitting a log-linear model.

Comment: @user777 sure, but read the code, it's not a logistic regression.

Comment: Read this and it will make more sense to **you**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_log-linear_model

Comment: @Dan My point is that the title mis-characterizes the question and confuses any answer. Saying that you used e.g., a probit link for a logistic model is nonsensical.

Comment: @Dan should not the log linear model still have beta_matrix*x_matrix? log-linear model should still have the linear function I've written in the question, which I can't see here.